# Elastic search configuration on server

Tags: php, elasticsearch, server

I am new in elastic search, I am building a search engine for my website using elasticsearch and php.

I want to update my project in my hosting server 
everything works perfectly in my localhost (my PC) but when I update the server

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Curl\CouldNotConnectToHost' with message 'couldn't connect to host' in /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/AbstractConnection.php:320
>   Stack trace: #0   /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(313): Elasticsearch\Connections\AbstractConnection->throwCurlException(7, 'couldn't connec...')
>   #1   /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(200): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->processCurlError(Object(Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException))
>   #2 /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(104): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->sendRequest(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), '{"query":{"bool...')
>   #3     /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/ in /home/uhuru372/public_html/unilodb/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/AbstractConnection.php on line 320`

Comment: perhaps port 9200 is being blocked?

Comment: Am not sure if that is the cause my guess is that there is a conflict on the host + the elastic connection because it require a` ./elasticsearch `  to start elasticsearch on localmachine so how do i do that on my server?